# Migration existing Standard GKE to Autopilot GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have Standard GKE cluster and want to migrate all my running services to new Autopilot cluster. I research official documentation and don't find anything how I can perform this migration

Comment: Start a GKE autopilot cluster and redeploy your services (reuse your YAML definition). Backup and restore your data manually, as you should do in case of cluster re-creation. Nothing magic or Built-In

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment this operation is not possible to convert Standard GKE cluster to Autopilot GKE .

In GKE Documentation [Autopilot overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) under Other limitations you can find section [No conversion](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#no_conversion):

> Converting Standard clusters to Autopilot mode and converting
> Autopilot clusters to Standard mode is not supported.

As stated by @guillaume blaquiere. You have to redeploy all your services. Backup and restore your data manually.

Comment: Don't think the page is accurate anymore. There is no section on limitations or anything that specifically rules out conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple cause it is K8 and more since you on GCP. Here is how:

1. 3-clicks to create new GKE autopilot cluster
2. First time deployment creation gives you auth token
3. Use that auth token to deploy services using CLI
4. YAML manifest pointing to existing nodes to be modified to new cluster
5. There will be a downtime for node draining - roughly 5-10 minutes per node